# React native ios build failed

Tags: ios, react-native

I followed the following tutorial of react native

[React Native Tutorial Link](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

I have successfully install the required stuffs

[Node, Watchman and flow version image link](http://grab.by/MIs8)

Next Init my project and even updated my xcode version

[Xcode version Link](http://grab.by/MIj0)

when i am trying to build the ios app. It throws an error which is not able to figure out by me as i am new to react.

The following is the error link

[Xcode Errors](http://grab.by/MIim)

[Log Errors](http://grab.by/MIiq)

Please guide me what's the exact issue with my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update to Xcode 7

As mentioned in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html):

> Xcode 7.0 or higher is required.

You are using **6.2**.