# AwesomeProject(ios) parse issue

Tags: react-native

After `react-native init AwesomeProject`

run in xcode show 127 issues.

one of them id this one:

> path/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:222:14:
>   Expected '>'
>
> 222 - (NSArray> *)methodsToExport;

I am using Xcode 6.3.1

Server under node.js 5.2.0

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/34278788/5042391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update to Xcode 7

As mentioned in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html):

> Xcode 7.0 or higher is required.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) 7.0 or higher is required. It can be installed from the App Store.